# change activity view while moving back from called activity when using tabs

Tags: android

i am using tabs.In a single tab i have several activity which is called one after one.In this i am calling getdecorview() when starting new activity and storing the view in arraylist and while moving back and I am getting the view from arraylist and setting it as content view.Now my peroblem is I want to set textview after moving back from called activity.For example i want to show it diagramatically                                                                      as              ---activity one----     --->called --activity two--  (get some value here from            user)  ------->now move back to -->activity one(here set value which got from activity two)

```
    how i can set the value which i got from second activity in activity one while using tabs? 
    thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, what you need is to launch the second activity via `Activity.startActivityForResult()`

The first activity must overrides the method

`onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

and the second activity must be launched as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sampleData", "This is Sample Data");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

Comment: I am using tabs so i am using  this View view=CartTab.group.getLocalActivityManager()  
            .startActivity("rss",new Intent(getDialogContext(),Addentry.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
            .getDecorView();  
             CartTab.group.replaceView(view);

Answer (score 0):

use startActivityForResult to call activity B.

check these docs and examples
1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
2. http://rahulonblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-startactivityforresult-example.html

Comment: i am using tabs containing several activity(called one after one) and calling it like that i think tabs will disappear from screen .I have mention above please check my problem

Comment: You can use Activity.setResult method to pass the data that you want to pass from the second activity to the first. The tabs will not disappear unless you are clearing them somehow in the onSTop method. If you are doing to you may want to save the state when the activity stops and use it to reopen them. But in normal scenario it should not be closed.

Comment: when starting activity tabs are getting invisible and activity occupying whole screen

Comment: That is another problem which should be asked as a separate question. It seems like you are adding tabs dynamically and also removing them in your onStop method. Without having any snippets of your code or understanding fully what you are doing, I cannot answer that. I would recommend you ask another question for that problem with a snippet of relevant code.